# make logo image responsive and aligh with content section

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to make my logo image responsive and align with my content section. When I put a padding on the div it look fine with a specific screen size. It doesn't work when I resize my screen. How can I make the logo image responsive and resize still align with my content section. Here is my code : Thanks

```css
body { background: lime !important; }
    .logo_section {
        background-color: white;
        padding:0 30px;
    }
    .content-section { 
        /* 10 px on top with nav bar */
        
        /* position: absolute; */
        position: relative;
        margin-top: -30px;
        z-index: 9999;
        
        
        padding:0 10px;
        background : white;
        border-color : black;        
        border-width: 5 px;
        border-style: solid;
    }
    
    .import-notes { 
        background : yellow;       
       /* add code to make in full width */
        margin-left: -10px;
        margin-right: -10px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
 </head>


<body>
<div class="logo_section">
<img class="img-responsive" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymxaR.png">
</div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">XYZ123</a>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="content-section">
      <p >(1)This is a test this is a test. This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.</p>
      <p >(2)This is a test </p>
      <p >(3)This is a test </p>
      <p >(4)This is a test </p>
      <p >(5)This is a test </p>
      <p >(6)This is a test </p>
      <p >(7)This is a test </p>
      <p >(8)This is a test </p>
      <p >(12)This is a test </p>
      <p class="import-notes">This is full width no padding</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Test</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
 body { background: lime !important; }
.logo_section {
    background-color: white;
    padding:0 30px;
}
.content-section { 
    /* 10 px on top with nav bar */

    /* position: absolute; */
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -30px;
    z-index: 9999;


    padding:0 10px;
    background : white;
    border-color : black;        
    border-width: 5 px;
    border-style: solid;
}

.import-notes { 
    background : yellow;       
   /* add code to make in full width */
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
</style>
</head>


<body>
<div class="logo_section">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymxaR.png">
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
 <div class="navbar-header">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">XYZ123</a>
 </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">

 <div class="content-section">
  <p >(1)This is a test this is a test. This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.</p>
  <p >(2)This is a test </p>
  <p >(3)This is a test </p>
  <p >(4)This is a test </p>
  <p >(5)This is a test </p>
  <p >(6)This is a test </p>
  <p >(7)This is a test </p>
  <p >(8)This is a test </p>
  <p >(12)This is a test </p>
  <p class="import-notes">This is full width no padding</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: Study the *Bootstrap* if you are using it. It will automatically solve your *DOM* related issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
 body { background: lime !important; }
.logo_section {
    background-color: white;
    padding:0 10px;
}
.content-section {  
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -30px;
    z-index: 9999;


    padding:0 10px;
    background : white;
    border-color : black;        
    border-width: 5 px;
    border-style: solid;
}

.import-notes { 
    background : yellow;        
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
    .wrapper_1{
        background : white;
    }
</style>   
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper_1">
<div class="container">

        <div class="logo_section">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymxaR.png">
        </div>



</div>
</div>   
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
             <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">XYZ123</a>
             </div>
            </nav>

<div class="container">

 <div class="content-section">
  <p >(1)This is a test this is a test. This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.</p>
  <p >(2)This is a test </p>
  <p >(3)This is a test </p>
  <p >(4)This is a test </p>
  <p >(5)This is a test </p>
  <p >(6)This is a test </p>
  <p >(7)This is a test </p>
  <p >(8)This is a test </p>
  <p >(12)This is a test </p>
  <p class="import-notes">This is full width no padding</p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

```css
body { background: lime !important; }
.logo_section {
    background-color: white;
    padding:0 10px;
}
.content-section {  
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -30px;
    z-index: 9999;


    padding:0 10px;
    background : white;
    border-color : black;        
    border-width: 5 px;
    border-style: solid;
}
    
.import-notes { 
    background : yellow;        
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
    .wrapper_1{
        background : white;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
 <body>
<div class="wrapper_1">
<div class="container">
    
        <div class="logo_section">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymxaR.png">
        </div>


        
</div>
</div>   
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
             <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">XYZ123</a>
             </div>
            </nav>
    
<div class="container">

 <div class="content-section">
  <p >(1)This is a test this is a test. This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.</p>
  <p >(2)This is a test </p>
  <p >(3)This is a test </p>
  <p >(4)This is a test </p>
  <p >(5)This is a test </p>
  <p >(6)This is a test </p>
  <p >(7)This is a test </p>
  <p >(8)This is a test </p>
  <p >(12)This is a test </p>
  <p class="import-notes">This is full width no padding</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have look this header aligned with below content and responsive issue resolve.

```css
<style type="text/css">
 body { background: lime !important; }
.logo_section {
    background-color: white;
    padding:0 30px;
}
.content-section {  
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -30px;
    z-index: 9999;


    padding:0 10px;
    background : white;
    border-color : black;        
    border-width: 5 px;
    border-style: solid;
}

.import-notes { 
    background : yellow;        
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
    .wrapper{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
    </style>
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="logo_section">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymxaR.png">
            </div>

            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
             <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">XYZ123</a>
             </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    
<div class="container">

 <div class="content-section">
  <p >(1)This is a test this is a test. This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.</p>
  <p >(2)This is a test </p>
  <p >(3)This is a test </p>
  <p >(4)This is a test </p>
  <p >(5)This is a test </p>
  <p >(6)This is a test </p>
  <p >(7)This is a test </p>
  <p >(8)This is a test </p>
  <p >(12)This is a test </p>
  <p class="import-notes">This is full width no padding</p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. see my code snippet, the logo is on top of the navbar.

Comment: Ok, so remove the wrapper class and then check.Then logo will be align left with navigation bar and content also remove padding with logo.

Comment: The logo need to align with content section not the navbar.

Comment: Can you template? So i can see what you want.

Comment: Thanks. It is partially working except that I need to make the navbar full width. Here is my modified code :

Comment: .logo_section {
    background-color: white;
    padding:0 10px;
}

      <div class="container">
        <div class="logo_section">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymxaR.png">
        </div>

            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
             <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">XYZ123</a>
             </div>
            </nav>
        
</div>